# Difference between the use of "resilience" and "resiliency"

Tags: differences, nouns, suffixes

I constantly hear people use the word "resiliency" (especially sports broadcasters and the like). I've always used "resilience" instead. Is there a preferred word to use in any given situation?

As far as I can gather they are exact synonyms.

Comment: The OED has 190 word-pairs of the same form as *resilience/resiliency*. Some of these sound weird, but many are normal. *abstinence/abstinency, complacence/complacency, emergence/emergency, expedience/expediency, flatulence/flatulency, impotence/impotency, potence/potency, prurience/pruriency, refulgence/refulgency, sufficience/sufficiency, transcendence/transcendency, truculence/truculency, virulence/virulency*, and many more.

Comment: @tchrist That's very interesting. Of those I almost always go for the former, with the exception of potency. complacence/complacency is an interesting pair because I actually use both of those words interchangeably.

Comment: I have never heard *emergency* used to mean *emergence*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Resiliency* is just a variant of *[resilience](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resiliency)*. Which one is used is a matter of style and personal preference. I would always use *resilience* because it's one syllable shorter than *resiliency*. Others may have different opinions. It doesn't matter because they are, as you suggest, exact synonyms, except for the pretentiousness of the longer word: *resiliency*. All verbosity is pretentious.

Comment: Don't you mean sesqipedalianism? ;-)

Comment: @Jim: It's sesquipedalianism too, but this is one of those cases in which I think a judgmental rather than a merely descriptive term is appropriate.

Comment: No, I meant you to say *all sesquipedalianism is pretentious* ;-)

Comment: @Jim: That's too restrictive. Sesquipedalianism is just one form of verbosity. Perhaps, though, I'm stretching the definition of verbosity in this case. But if only speech is analyzed, then there is only a single stream of sound and verbosity is measured by length of time and not necessarily number of words. We do not disagree. :-)

Comment: Sometimes my sense of humor fails to kick in. <(B=O

Answer (score 5):

Resilience is the more accepted form in the USA.

> [I]n today’s English, resilience is far more common than resiliency, especially outside the U.S. and Canada. In North American publications, resilience appears about four times as often as resiliency. Outside North America, resiliency appears only rarely.
>
> Though resilience is more common, resiliency is not incorrect. Both words are around five centuries old, and it wasn’t until the late 19th century that resilience prevailed by a significant margin. Still, there’s no reason not to use the shorter, more common form. - [*Grammarist*](http://grammarist.com/usage/resilience-resiliency/)

Answer (score 0):

Resiliency has become very popular with sports broadcasters when describing the emotional grit of a team in competition.  It is part of an alarming trend for former athletes to try to appear professorial in their post career work in television.  It falls into the category of wearing unneeded glasses, never referring to a ball or a team without the full reference to the sport (*football* instead of just ball, *football team* instead of just team etc.).  I wish all of that would die a quick death but it has incredible resilience.